# How to access the value in array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, foreach

Hi folks i am new to angular please help me how to access the value inside the objects. I want to access the SuccessCount in this Array

Here is my try

```
goodResponse=[
    {compId: 1, companyName: "A", pendingCount: 0, successCount: 0, apiErrorCount: 0, …}
   {compId: 1, companyName: "B", pendingCount: 0, successCount: 0, apiErrorCount: 0, …}
   {compId: 3, companyName: "C", pendingCount: 0, successCount: 0, apiErrorCount: 0, …}
    {compId: 4, companyName: "D", pendingCount: 0, successCount: 0, apiErrorCount: 0, …}
]

let _graphTotal = this.goodResponse;
let _graphTotalCount = []
_graphTotal.forEach(element => {
   console.log("total Count", element[0].successCount)
});
```

Comment: Try `element.successCount` instead of `element[0].successCount`

Comment: i tried but it return 0

Comment: Because provided Objects have `successCount: 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run with ForEach loop, each "element" is a data in the array so you need to write:

```
element.successCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating over the array goodResponse you need to access the object, so it should be like

```
_graphTotal.forEach(element => {
   console.log("total Count", element.successCount)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `successCount` of the current element, instead of trying to access a non-existing element of successCount.

```
_graphTotal.forEach(element => {
   console.log("total Count", element.successCount)
});
```

Comment: i tried but it return 0

Comment: @yahiyarockz yes, it will return 0 because that is how you hard coded the value to inside your question

Comment: Please explain what is your expected result also and why?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `element[0].successCount` with `element.successCount`.

Comment: i tried but it return 0

Comment: i tried but it return 0

Comment: In your code all instances of `successCount` are set to 0. That is the expected result.

Comment: Please explain what is your expected result also and why?

Answer (score 0):

Each element from map returns an object. So that the first element returned by map will be the 0th index of array. Now you have a object as your first element and you need to use dot(.) to access inside the object. So that the function becomes element.successCount